# Order MY answers by accepted?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

When I view my profile page it shows my answers and I can list them by: Recent, Views, Newest, Votes. I would like to also be able to order them by accepted or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative you can use is to do a search of `user:me isaccepted:1` in the search box. This will show you all of your accepted answers - and as an added bonus sort them by votes/date/activity to your needs. You can use `user:me isaccepted:0` to get the unaccepted answers.

Comment: Naturally, this won't give you both at the same time - but that's why it is an alternative.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks for the nifty trick!... By the way do you know of a list that says all the things like this you can put in the search bar? The only one I knew of was `votes:N`

Comment: If you use an empty search, you'll arrive at the Search Options page that lists all of them. For your convenience, though, a URL! [♪](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=)