# Include my accepted answers on the tab "profile/activity/accepted"?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, tabs

I was disappointed to see that the tab `profile/activity/accepted` shows only the accepted answers I have marked on other people answers

> Proposal: I think it should also show the accepted answers marked by other
>   people on my answers

Not only because it would make sense, but because I failed to find a way to somehow search my accepted answers list, (I know how to manually search for them on my answers, but this task gets harder and harder every time the list increases).

The closest thing I found to search a list of accepted stuff posted by me is [this approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58045/179635), but it is for questions only.

<del>But even if we manage to find a way to find this precious list</del> <sup>(edit: Nick Craver♦ [found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132123/179635) a way)</sup>, I think that nobody should struggle this much to find it, it should be openly available trough this tab!

Answer (score 3):

> The closest thing I found to search a list of accepted stuff posted by me is [this approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58045/179635), but it is for questions only.

I'm not sure where that interpretation comes from...it's actually the opposite (only answers)...[look at the results of this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:908879%20isaccepted:1): `user:908879 isaccepted:1`

That's the list of all your *answers* that have been accepted, if you're looking for questions *of yours* with an accepted answer, [you use `hasaccepted:1` like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:908879%20hasaccepted:1): `user:908879 hasaccepted:1`

Comment: unaccepted because I read this [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133083/179635)