# When will a feature-request be marked as either status-completed or status-declined?

Tags: support, meta

I recently asked this [feature-request question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131208/184933) here on Meta, and am wondering when it will be addressed and marked as either [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Is there a defined time-frame for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), or does it just depend on availability?

Comment: In 6-8 weeks, we're told.

Comment: Probably tomorrow, or in a few years. Maybe never. Who knows?

Comment: @Rosinante, ok, thanks, but its not documented anywhere? I couldnt find it.

Comment: Seems like there should be another status then, maybe something like status-in-progress. Is that worth another feature-request that may never get addressed :)

Comment: the only think for sure is that dumb proposals will be declined right away within few minutes/hours of posted, for the rest see the ans of Pekka

Comment: @Brady There's [status-planned], though it doesn't get a lot of use.

Comment: If you're **really** lucky, [it only takes 4 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118740).

Comment: [6 - 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/419), if you're lucky :)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are currently 10,135 questions tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Of those, [7,882 of them have not been marked completed, declined, or otherwise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-declined+-status-bydesign+-status-planned+-status-deferred+-status-review).

Just to give you some perspective, there are **lots** of feature requests. They tend to gravitate towards the ones that are very popular (or very *unpopular*) and actually make sense to them when it comes to investing their time.

Another thing to keep in mind (don't know if this actually relates to you): don't mark accepted answers on your meta posts if it *hasn't* actually been resolved yet. The answer may be good and represent a valid way of achieving something, but if you still expect the feature to actually get implemented, you shouldn't mark the question itself as "answered." That makes it look like you've accepted an alternative and the feature you requested is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that, I imagine they get alot of feature-requests. I was wondering about having accepted a feature-request answer and how it would affect the status of it. What you mention makes sense. I think there are several points here worth documenting in the FAQ, how should I go about proposing them?