# My own questions viewed - filter/sort by whether I accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

**Related:**

- [Order MY answers by accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58042/order-my-answers-by-accepted)
- [Is there a way to filter/sort your questions by whether you have accepted an answer on your profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79567/is-there-a-way-to-filter-sort-your-questions-by-whether-you-have-accepted-an-ans)
- [Filter questions with no accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86460/filter-questions-with-no-accepted-answer)

When I ask questions on SO, I often don't accept answers straight away, either because I need some time to try answers out or because for some more subjective questions the answers may be slow in coming and it may take a few days for a number of answers to come in for me to review.  In the mean time I may ask more questions.  (By now, I have asked 87 questions on SO, but I'm sure there are members with a lot more questions.)  Sometimes I forget to go back to accept an answer, especially if while waiting for answers I managed to work around the problem.

Once in a while I would go into my profile, switch to the *questions* view and go through all questions without accepted answers reviewing them and accepting where applicable.  Unfortunately, there's no easy way for me to see my questions without accepted answers.

I know I can use link https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0 to access the list of my question without accepted answers, however I don't remember that link off the top of my head an have to look it up on meta every time.

Ideally, I would like to have an option to sort my questions by "accepted answer" so that questions with no accepted answers would appear at the top, in addition to existing sort by votes, activity, newest and view.

Comment: One more related/possible dupe link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58042/order-my-answers-by-accepted

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks.  It's almost duplicate, although not quite the same.  I'm asking the sorting order as an option, whereas that question's OP was happy with the search option.

Comment: *"however I don't remember that link off the top of my head an have to look it up on meta every time"* — you're using a browser that does support bookmarks, right? Alternatively, just create a (or [edit an existing](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a)) Greasemonkey script and add that link e.g. in all users' profile pages, including your own.